# java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService runs very infrequent

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, runnable, java.util.concurrent, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a client application, where a runnable has to run in a fix period. Therefore I use the `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` as follows:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
            Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableClass,
            period,period,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

As long as the workload is low, the task is scheduled in the defined period, i.e if the client receives no messages from the server. But if the server shoots out messages at full throttle, the `runnableClass.run()` is not executed on time. I feel like the time between the execution increases exponentially. But the Computer still runs smooth.

All `Exceptions` are catched inside `run()` and if I decrease the messages send from the server, the task is scheduled more often.

Why does that happen?

*EDIT: The task needs a lot of resources and it is using `Rserve` to get predictions computed in `R`. There are probably up to 5000 calls to `R` in one task.*

*I made some tests regarding the time of the task. The task was always done in under a second, while the period was between 3 and 20 seconds.*

Comment: Can you describe the characteristics of the scheduled task in some detail? CPU or I/O bound? Common resources? Average execution times?

Comment: So how many Rserve servers are there? This looks like a resource to me where you may have contention. Having more threads in parallel than there are Rserve servers would not make sense. - Also I now what "full throttle" means on my jalopy, but how many requests per minute is that on your speedometer? Scheduling at a fixed rate is *not* the best answer for dealing with many tasks, it may avoid synchronisation issues. I don't want to be harsh, but have you had your design reviewed thoroughly?

Comment: The processing of the messages is not coupled to the task, that is supposed to run at a fixed rate. The idea is to use the fixed rate task to batch-process the stream of incoming messages. Therefore the relevant information of the messages is collected and shall be processed at a fixed rate. Otherwise it is very though to make use of the batch-processing.

Comment: there is just one Rserve server. And the server (for testing and not written by me) sends messages until there are 2000 threads at client side are open and then waits 100ms.

Comment: Re "otherwise...tough to make use of batch-processing": Normally messages to be processed by some entity are put into a queue, which serializes input for the processor. Collecting them and throwing a bundle at the processor is not the generally approved solution. - But you have lost me now - I'm at a loss regarding the overall scenario - which entitiy sends messages with which frequency to what processor?

Answer (score 0):

How many threads are you running and how many cores do you have? Can it happen that you serve every request from a different thread, and the context switchings make your app run slower and slower?

Take care not to have much more CPU-bound threads than cores.
(Just a guess, sorry if it's way off)

Also, do you need a scheduled thread pool executor wit core size of 10? Isn't a SingleThreadScheduledExecutor enough for the scheduled task?

Comment: Questions are not answers! Move this to a comment.

Comment: I'd gladly do that, but when I tried the last time 50 reputation was the minimum to comment a question ;-)

Comment: Take care: such answers are typically downvoted which will reduce your rep even more. - The usual advice is to be patient and collect points until you may comment.